# Migration to VS2015 DLL not found

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, migrating

I created an application with VS2013 that worked perfect on my Dell desktop. At its core, it uses a DLL located at C:\lcms2.dll. Really, flawless. Today, I installed VS2015 Community onto my SurfacePro3, copied the Solution directory only to hit a wall, "DLL not found". I thought, perhaps, some "security" feature I know nothing about but even after locating the DLL to the C:\TMP directory, I still got the dreaded DLL not found error.

Initial search on this problem are not turning much so I uninstalled VS2015 and currently install VS2013 on my Surface... We'll see. But I'm open to suggestions if anyone has any ideas. Thank's.

Comment: Could it be a 32/64 bit issue? Or is only signed code allowed in the 2015 project?

Comment: I installed VS2013 on a Win7 64bit machine and it worked. The DLL was found exactly where I specified in code. Beats me.

Comment: So most probably the error message is misleading. The DLL file is found, but it is recognized as being compiled for the wrong architecture. Or the matching runtime is not found. You could try to use dumpbin or similar to find the DLL's dependencies.

Comment: This is mot likely, Georg -- thank's!